# ReactNative - Video Player With Subtitle Support

Tags: react-native

I want to play video from `url` **with support for subtitle**.

is there any component that support subtitles in video for `react native` ?

Comment: Ever find an answer?

Answer (score 2):

There's a [PR/discussion to add subtitle support](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/pull/972) to react-native-video component. I think if/once that gets merged, it should be the official way. I'd show an example here but the final API is not decided yet.

There's also a fork at [react-native-video-controls](https://github.com/pegahtech/react-native-video-controls) that renders subtitles on top of the video using JavaScript, which you might try.